# How to handle Foreign Keys with Entity Framework

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two entities.  Groups.  Pools.  A Group can create **many** pools.

So I setup my Pool table to have a GroupID foreign key.

My code:

```
using (entity _db = new entity()) {
    Pool p     = new Pool();
    p.Name     = "test";
    p.Group.ID = "5";
    _db.AddToPool(p);
}
```

This doesn't work.  I get a null reference exception on p.Group.

How do I go about creating a new "Pool" and associating a GroupID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either load the existing Group object, say `group`, from your context and then set `p.Group = group` or with EF4 you can set the `GroupID` on your pool directly since it can expose the foreign key properties if you specify that in the EDMX.

Comment: I ended up just using p.Group = group;